# TypeError: string indices must be integers when using in cartopy but normal printing works fine

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, cartopy

I am trying to create a flight route  map using cartopy. I have to add the destination names on the map and to achieve it i am using this code:

```
origin_lat = 59.41329956
origin_lon= 24.83279991    
data = pd.read_csv("merged.csv", skiprows=[1])
```

This csv file has few columns and one column is  called IATA from where I am trying to extract those location strings.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
lon = data['Longitude'][i]
lat =  data['Latitude'][i]
label = data['IATA'][i]

plt.plot([origin_lon, lon], [origin_lat, lat],
     color='red', linewidth=1,
     transform=ccrs.Geodetic(),
     )

print(label) # when i use only print it shows all the strings available in IATA column
plt.text(lon, lat, label[i],
     horizontalalignment='right',
     transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

But when I plot in map it shows the error

[36 rows x 15 columns]

```
AMS
ATH
TXL
BRU
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\spyderPython\hw3\readCSV.py", line 65, in <module>
    plt.text(lon, lat, label[i],

IndexError: string index out of range
```

can someone advise please what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you fix the indents in the for loop? For instance, is the print inside the for?

Comment: When you `print(label)`, what do you get? If its just a string like "AMS", then `label[i]` isn't what you want. I think `plt.text(lon, lat, label, ...)` solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the label again here:

```py
plt.text(lon, lat, label[i],
     horizontalalignment='right',
     transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

which I assume your `label` is already a string, and `range(len(data))` is bigger than the len of your `label`. That is why you get an IndexError, simply switch that code with this:

```py
plt.text(lon, lat, label,
     horizontalalignment='right',
     transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```